# Smoothness of Hilbert scheme of rational normal curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, hilbert-schemes

I'm trying to solve Exercise 1.26 from the book "Moduli of Curves"
by Harris and Morrison on page 14:

***Exercise (1.26)*** Determine the normal bundle to the rational normal
curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^r =: X$ and show, by computing its $h^0$,
that the Hilbert scheme
parameterizing such curves is smooth at any point corresponding to
a rational normal curve.

The part I can't solve is that one how the dimension of global sections
of the normal bundle $h^0= \dim_{\mathbb{C}}H^0(C, N_{C / X})$  imply that the Hilbert scheme $\mathcal{H}$
is smooth at $[C]$.

Since $C$ is rational normal curve $C \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ and the long
exact cohomology sequence of the
exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathcal{T}_{C} \rightarrow 
\mathcal{T}_{X}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{C} \rightarrow 
\mathcal{N}_{X|C} \rightarrow 0$ gives

$$\operatorname{dim} H^0 (C,N_{C/X}) = \operatorname{dim} 
H^0 (C,T_X \otimes O_C) -3 = (r+1) \cdot \dim \ H^0 (C,O_C(1))-3$$

(the last one is consequence of Euler sequence). Fine now we know $h^0$. Immediately before it was shown that the tangent space of
$\mathcal{H}$ at $[C]$ is

$$T_{[C]}\mathcal{H}= H^0(C, N_{C / X})$$

Per definition a scheme $X$ is smooth at a point $P$ if the dimension of
tangent space at this point coinsides with *local dimension*: ie there exist
an open affine subscheme $U \subset X$ with $P \in U$ and
$\dim_P T= \dim \ U$.

Working through previous pages I nowhere found informations about
local dimension of the Hilbert scheme parametrizing rational normal
curve so I have no idea how can I compare the dimension of
$T_{[C]}\mathcal{H}= H^0(C, N_{C / X})$ which I calculated above
with the local dimension of $\mathcal{H}$.

Can anybody give me some hints how to attack this part of the exercise?

Comment: You can represent the open subscheme of the Hilbert scheme as a GIT quotient. For instance for twisted cubics, one needs to choose 4 homogeneous polynomials of degree $3$ in $X$, $Y$, up to common scaling and then quotient out the $\mathbf{PGL}_2$-action on $X$, $Y$. This gives a $12$-dimensional component of the Hilbert scheme.

Comment: @EvgenyShinder: Could you explain why the Hilbert scheme of rational normal curves can be modeled locally by such quotient? The reason why exactly 4 homogeneous poynomial of degree $3$ do the job isn't clear to me. Or could you give a reference where this constrcution you have described can be looked up?

Comment: At least on the level of points of the moduli space, to specify a rational normal curve of degree $r$, you can first parametrize it as a map from $\mathbf{P}^1$ to $\mathbf{P}^r$ of degree $r$ (Veronese embedding). This amounts to choosing the basis of degree $r$ polynomials in $X$, $Y$. Two maps give the same curve if they differ by linear action on $X$, $Y$.